# Installing Win8 from internal hard drive

Tags: windows-8

so ive downloaded the Iso but i cannot burn it or have an external drive with me.

Is it possible to create a partition on my hard drive and extract the iso file there then boot from it and install into another partition?

Say i have c:, d: and e:
c: has win7, d: will have the extracted win8 iso and e: will be the final installation partition. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you how to do that, but I think it should be possible to install it to a virtual disk from within windows 7 and then boot to that virtual disk:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/haroldwong/archive/2012/08/18/how-to-create-windows-8-vhd-for-boot-to-vhd-using-simple-easy-to-follow-steps.aspx

Let me know how you get on, I will be interested to know if it works.

Comment: ill try it in a minute

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can...

Still in the order of ease...

1. Can't u use a USB/Pendrive. A 4GB would be more than enough.
2. Although a clean install is always recommended, but if it's not necessary, then simply use PowerISO & install Windows 8
3. Else, Here's the solution you want: Use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)
   (I can assure you that it can be done using EasyBCD, but the process is slightly tricky. Great if you can figure it out. Else, I'll update it soon if you can't, as I'll have to ask my buddy for the same.)